# How to clone computer image A to the computer B

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, disk-cloning

I'm setting up computer for business purposes and I set up the main one as every employee should have. Whole process takes +/- 2 hours.

Is there a faster way to clone whatever apps/settings are installed on all the computer without wasting 2 hours for each PC? I've thought about doing it with the System Restore in Windows but it doesn't seem to work since some computers do not have the same SSD size then the main one.

Thank you.

Comment: Clonezilla.....

Comment: Please kindly check if this can help you: [The best way to clone a hard drive (least time-consuming, error-prone)](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/08/29/the-best-way-to-clone-a-hard-drive-least-time-consuming-error-prone/)